# NSPredicate to fetch the specific data in the NSSet CoreData?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data

I have table A and B. A and B have one to many relationship.I am fetching data from the A but while fetching data i get all the data of B in NSSet.But I Want to have some specific data of B in NSSet while i am fetching data from A.

Comment: Can you please show us some code what have you done so far ?

Comment: Since you have not provided any code I can give you a link to good resource for [Core data](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/tag/core-data/) only.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply predicate on NSSet. NSSet has instance method-

```
- (NSSet *)filteredSetUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate

Example from apple documentation

NSSet *sourceSet =
    [NSSet setWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", @"Four", nil];
NSPredicate *predicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith 'T'"];
NSSet *filteredSet =
    [sourceSet filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];
// filteredSet contains (Two, Three)
```

Comment: I am taking about fetching data CoreDtaa

Comment: I know i can apply filter on the NSSet but when i am fetching data from core data i want sepecific data in the NSSet only.